# Zoo: How to set categories view access only to registered users?

Tags: zoo-cck

I am looking all over the Zoo, to see where I can set viewing access level for categories. I want to give access to them only for registered users.

Is there something that I am missing, or there is not support for this by default ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although using access levels for the menu items that holds each category is close to the solution, categories will still be accessible outside of a menu item.

I ended up, hard-coding some access checks on the zoo templates.

Answer (score 1):

The only ACL Management I can see for the categories is, if you go to:

> **Components** >> **Zoo** >> **Config** (tab) >> **Permissions** (dropdown)

Else the only other method I can see is setting the access level for each Item belonging to a specific category

Comment: I know about the categories permissions, but these are for what users can do with the categories, but not who can view them in front-end. The only thing I see, is to assign access on the menu items that hold a category - but I guess they will still be accessible out of that menu item. I am afraid that my requirement might only be possible by hardcoding it on the zoo-templates level.